# Как загрузить zip-архив из памяти?

Tags: c++, zip

Допустим есть у меня файл test.smp (самопальный), на самом деле это заксореный (XOR) zip-архив. Далее я его открываю, расксориваю и теперь он у меня в памяти.

Можно ли получить дескриптор или хэндл для функции **zip_fdopen**?
Или же придется сохранять zip, а потом заново загружать функцией **zip_open**?

Comment: Если Вашему zip_... нужен FILE \*, то см. `man fmemopen`

Comment: @avp, а в какой либе находится fmemopen ? Не могу найти инфу по ней.
P.S. юзаю visual c++.

Comment: @NameX: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12249610/276994

Comment: В linux в стандартной libc.